# HtmlAgilityPack exception has been thrown when used in deployed SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

Trying to read from: sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Using VS 2017 (15.6.4), leveraging C#, with HtmlAgilityPack 1.7.4, deployed to my OS2016 SSIS Server

When these commands run:

```
var html = @"http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
```

I always get:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I ensured the HTMLAgilityPack.dll was deployed to the GAC correctly and validated such as:

```
C:\...\gacutil>gacutil -l HtmlAgilityPack
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

```
HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 1
```

When testing within VS2017 it runs fine, w/o error or issue (after I registered it to the GAC).

Comment: Any more information about the exception that was thrown?  It might be logged in the NT Event logs.  Otherwise, you could maybe use log4net to grab the exception info and log it.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing in event logs, besides the failure itself. I will try to get log4net to work, but I suspect this is an inability for SSIS to retrieve the HtmlAgilityPack dll, so I may have similar issues with log4net. We will see!

Answer (score 0):

So, this was a huge oversight on my part. Walking through the Log4Net install suggestion for SSIS helped greatly.

It seems that I registered the dll's on the DB Server, but the standalone SSIS server did not have the dll's registered. I suspect it was the SSIS Server side that my problems were coming from.

On a side note, so that I did not need to install anything special to use the "gacutil.exe", I copied from my local computer (which has VS2017 installed) gacutil.exe, gacutil.exe.config, and gacutlrc.dll to a folder on my server. With those 3 files, I was able to register the HtmlAgilityPack.dll without issue. Command executed: gacutil -I HtmlAgilityPack.dll